# Sorting data and rendering on UI not working with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and I want to create a list which can be sorted with price(salary). My api response is suppose -

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name": "Person 1",
        "salary": 300
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name": "Person 2",
        "salary": 100
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name": "Person 3",
        "salary": 200
    }
]
```

I'm trying to use hooks `useState` and `useEffect` to get my data and populate the UI

```
const salary = () => {

    const [salaryState, setsalaryState] = useState([]);
    const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);
    const [geterror, setError] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://apiCall')
        .then(response => {
            setsalaryState(response.data);
            setLoad(true);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setError(error.message);
            console.log('error', geterror);
        })
    },[]);

    const handleSalrySort = () => {
        var sortAsc = salaryState.sort((a,b) => {
            return parseFloat(a.salary) - parseFloat(b.salary)
        });
        setsalaryState(sortAsc);
        console.log('sortAsc', sortAsc);
    }

    if(load){
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid pt-3">
                <div onClick={handleSalrySort}>Salary - Low to High</div>
                {
                    salaryState.map((sal,index) => {
                        return(
                            <div>
                                Person : {sal.name}
                                Salary: {sal.salary}
                            </div>      
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }else{
        return(
            <div></div>
        )
    }
}
```

Ater the `handleSalrySort` function I'm able to update the state `salaryState` but it's not reflecting on the UI. Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array is reference type. hence, you need to get new copy of data by using map,slice etc. otherwise, React wont detect that data has changed as it points to same memory reference.

I have used slice() method. To sort in DESC order sort should should return `b-a`

```
 const handleSalrySort = () => {
    var sortAsc = salaryState.slice().sort((a, b) => {
      return parseFloat(b.salary) - parseFloat(a.salary);
    });
    setsalaryState(sortAsc);
    console.log("sortAsc", sortAsc);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine I didnt find any issues on that. Already the data in asc order only. So on click of that no changes detected. If still is not working please create the fiddle/sandbox link with appropriate data

For your reference, [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-useeffect-rlthw)

Comment: Sorry about that, shuffled the data a little bit

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting your data in the **then** block of your **axios** call immediately after fetching it but before updating the state. Update the state in **useEffect** with an already sorted array of your data. It is more intuitive way to do it.